# Mixed modelling with little data in one group

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm fitting a mixed model to a dataset, and I'm getting some results that I don't understand.  Here is a simple example of what I'm doing in R:

```
library(lme4)
d = data.frame(time = c(rep(1:10, times = 4)),
               group = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 10),
               Value = c(100 + 10*1:10 + rnorm(10)*10, #A
                          60 + 8.2*1:10 + rnorm(10)*10, #B
                          130 + 11*1:10 + rnorm(10)*10, #C
                          c(rep(NA, 4), 3, rep(NA, 5))))
modelFormula = Value ~ -1 + (1 + time|group)
model = lme4::lmer(formula = modelFormula, data = d, REML = FALSE)
predict(model, newdata=d)
coef(model)
```

I have four groups, three of which have data for all ten years.  The other group has a single observations, and I want to use a mixed model to take advantage of the information in the other groups to estimate the value in this group.

In group D, I only have one observation.  How, then, can I estimate a slope and intercept for this point?  My initial guess was that we can use the information in the other groups to determine these parameters, but that doesn't seem to be the case as the intercept and slope for group D are quite different than groups A-C.  Is this model somehow estimating the slope relative to the intercept, so that the percent growth rate for each group is similar?